# trying to understand php's zvals

Tags: php, php-internals

I'm trying to understand PHP's zvals. So consider the following code:

```
<?php
$randomByteString = 'abcd';

$val = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
    $val |= ord($randomByteString[$i]) << ($i * 8);
}

echo $val;
```

It seems to me that a zval would be created for each of these statements:

- $i = 0
- ++$i
- $i * 8
- $randomByteString[$i]
- ord($randomByteString[$i])
- and on any change to $val

Is that correct?

Comment: No, why should a new zval be created for `++$i` when there's already a zval for `$i`? All you're doing is modifying the value stored in that zval

Comment: Likewise for changes to `$val`, you're changing an existing value in an existing zval, so there's no need to create a new zval

Comment: There is a [whole section in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php) about them.

Comment: Even better, read these posts by nikic https://nikic.github.io/2015/05/05/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-1.html He did a lot of work on internals for php 7 and gives some excellent information on how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite. Let's go through it line-by-line, covering how PHP 5 would handle these zvals.

```
<?php
$randomByteString = 'abcd';
```

A new zval containing `'abcd'` is created and now `$randomByteString` points to it.

Zval count so far: 1

```
$val = 0;
```

A new zval containing `0` is created and now `$val` points to it.

Zval count so far: 2

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
```

The first time we run through this, we create a zval for `0` and point `$i` to it.

Comparing `$i` and `4` might create a boolean zval temporarily. My memory of what PHP 5 does here is fuzzy, it might not do this under-the-hood. It doesn't matter for our overall count though, because it'd be thrown away immediately.

Incrementing `$i` doesn't create a zval, it just changes the number inside the zval `$i` already points to.

Zval count so far: 3 (not including temporary zval as it was thrown away)

```
    $val |= ord($randomByteString[$i]) << ($i * 8);
```

Accessing `$randomByteString[$i]` will create a zval containing a single-byte string. Passing it to `ord()` will discard that zval and create a new zval containing an integer.

Multiplying it `8` by `$i` will create a new zval.

Left shifting our `ord()` result by our `$i` result will create a new zval and chuck away our two input zvals.

Finally, using `|=` with `$val` will change the value in `$val` and chuck away our left shift result. `$val` already exists so we just change the contents rather than making a new zval for it.

Zval count so far: 4

```
}

echo $val;
```

Echo won't create any zvals.

At the end of the script, you have 4 zvals around.

By the way, the zvals created for `$i < 4`, `$randomByteString[$i]`, `($i * 8)` and `<<` are all *temporary* zvals: they don't cause new memory allocations, instead they're stored in a special area of memory used for temporary values. This means that there's no performance penalty for creating these temporary values. The other zvals (including `ord()` for some reason, function calls are inefficient), on the other hand, do require memory allocations.

Also, this is all just for PHP 5. PHP 7 handles zvals a lot more smartly, so that usually there's no separate memory allocations needed for them.